# How can i replace strings in to resource files from web.sitemap and telerik menu for multilanguage support in asp.net(c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net

my web.sitemap is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0"  >
  <siteMapNode url="~/Index.aspx?id=Home" title="Dashboard" description="">
    <!-- Catalog Management-->
    <siteMapNode url="~/Index.aspx?id=CategoryHome&amp;category=CatalogManagement" title="Catalog Management" description="">
      <siteMapNode url="~/Index.aspx?id=ProductManager" title="Products" description="">
        <siteMapNode url="~/Index.aspx?id=EditProduct" title="Add Product" description="" />
      </siteMapNode>
      <siteMapNode url="~/Index.aspx?id=Attributes" title="Variations" description="">
        <siteMapNode url="~/Index.aspx?id=AddEditVariation" title="Add/Edit Variations" description="" />
      </siteMapNode>
      <siteMapNode url="~/Index.aspx?id=GiftCertificateManager" title="Generate Gift Cards" description="" />
      <siteMapNode url="~/Index.aspx?id=DepartmentManager" title="Departments" description="">
        <siteMapNode url="~/Index.aspx?id=AddEditDepartment" title="Add/Edit Department" description=""/>
      </siteMapNode>
      <siteMapNode url="~/Index.aspx?id=ManufacturerManager" title="Manufacturers" description="" >
        <siteMapNode url="~/Index.aspx?id=AddEditManufacturer" title="Add Manufacturer" description="" />
      </siteMapNode>
      <siteMapNode url="~/Index.aspx?id=WarehouseManager" title="Warehouses" description="">
        <siteMapNode url="~/Index.aspx?id=EditWarehouse" title="Add Warehouse" description="" />
      </siteMapNode>
    </siteMapNode>
```

one more XML is there for Telerik menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<PanelItems>
  <PanelItem Text="Dashboard" NavigateUrl="../Index.aspx?id=Home"></PanelItem>
  <PanelItem Text="Catalog Management" NavigateUrl="../Index.aspx?id=CategoryHome&amp;category=CatalogManagement">                  <!--  -->
    <PanelItem Text="Products" NavigateUrl="../Index.aspx?id=ProductManager"/>                          <!-- Product Manager -->
    <PanelItem Text="Variations" NavigateUrl="../Index.aspx?id=Attributes"/>
    <PanelItem Text="Generate Gift Cards" NavigateUrl="../Index.aspx?id=GiftCertificateManager"/>       <!-- Gift Certificate Manager -->
    <PanelItem Text="Departments" NavigateUrl="../Index.aspx?id=DepartmentManager"/>                    <!-- Department Manager -->
    <PanelItem Text="Manufacturers" NavigateUrl="../Index.aspx?id=ManufacturerManager"/>                <!-- Manufacturer Manager -->
    <PanelItem Text="Warehouses" NavigateUrl="../Index.aspx?id=WarehouseManager"/>                      <!-- Warehouse Manager -->
  </PanelItem>
  <PanelItem Text="Customer Management" NavigateUrl="../Index.aspx?id=CategoryHome&amp;category=CustomerManagement">                <!--  -->
    <PanelItem Text="Customers" NavigateUrl="../Index.aspx?id=CustomerManager" />
    <PanelItem Text="Export Subscribers" NavigateUrl="../Index.aspx?id=ExportSubscriptions"/>           <!-- Export Subscribers -->
  </PanelItem>
  <PanelItem Text="Order Management" NavigateUrl="../Index.aspx?id=CategoryHome&amp;category=OrderManagement">                      <!--  -->
    <PanelItem Text="Orders" NavigateUrl="../Index.aspx?id=FindOrders" />                               <!-- Find Orders -->
    <PanelItem Text="Shopping Carts" NavigateUrl="../Index.aspx?id=CartView"/>                          <!-- View Cart -->
    <PanelItem Text="Wish Lists" NavigateUrl="../Index.aspx?id=ViewWishList"/>                          <!-- View Wish List -->
  </PanelItem>
```

and one more thig is I am using 5 resource file for 5 menus

how to convert XML in to resources

Comment: Ok, that makes no sense what-so-ever. What are these mysterious resources you allude to? What is Leftmenu, and how does it relate to XML? What actually is web.sitemap?

Comment: Right, clearer with the fixed XML, but I still have no real idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Is the question: "How do I copy and paste from this XML into a resource file format?"  If so, which application is using the resource file?  Struts?  Something else?  Which "resources" should this XML create?

Comment: its in ASP.NET,,left menu is coming on left,,and if you go through each menu to internally the bread crumb is showed from web.sitemap

Comment: @prg: What?  Please update your question with additional facts.  What ASP.NET resources are you trying to create from this XML?

Comment: I need to change strings in xml in to resources(.resx)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I fully understand the question. If you want to take these XML and instead of deploying them along with your apllication to have them as a resource in an assembly then you need to do the following:

- select the file in the Solution Explorer
- open Properties window (F4)
- set Embedded Resource in Build Action

Now your XML is embedded as a resource in your assembly. Now the question is how to access it. For this use the following code:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("<default namespace.>MyFile.xml");
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
// now process the stream the way you want -- for example streamReader.ReadToEnd() to get it as a text
```

There is a good CodeProject article called [Embedded resources](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/embeddedresources.aspx).